# PHP include printing unexpectedly

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to use a PHP include or require like this:

```
        <div id="menu">
          <?php 
            include("tmpl/links.php");
          ?>
        </div>
```

And it's including the links, but it's also printing some garbage. It's printing this above the menu:

```
        ï»¿
```

This doesn't mean anything at all to me. It's happening if I use include or require. Here's links.php, for good measure:

```
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="index.php">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="schedule.php">Schedule/Results</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="roster.php">Roster</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="coaches.php">Coaching Staff</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="aboutus.php">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="prospective.php">Prospective Players</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="links.php">Links</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="photos.php">Photos</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="contactUs.php">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="https://www.facebook.com">Facebook</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

Can anyone help me figure out how to eliminate the garbage (ï»¿)?

Comment: I had that happen years ago. I copied the code into a new notepad file and deleted the old one and that fixed it. Never figured out what it was.

Comment: Hmm... [BOM](http://rusanu.com/2009/05/21/have-you-met-i%C2%BB%C2%BF-say-hello-to-my-bom/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like it might be an encoding issue.  Make sure your text is UTF8 encoded (without BOM).  I like to use Notepad++ to do this.

Comment: The without BOM seems to be the thing that fixed it; switching to just UTF-8 didn't change it. Thanks!

Comment: UTF-8 is not supposed to have a BOM at all - it's meaningless for it and a bug to include it. Also, setting the output charset to utf-8 will hide the BOM (if there is one), but it's still there. This will will make it impossible to set headers using php because headers must be sent before output - but the BOM will output before any PHP code runs. And finally, since you are seeing those char in the output, you are not correctly setting the charset of the output, so fix that too. `ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');`

Answer (score 5):

It's the UTF-16 BOM (Byte order mark).

Solution: Never use UTF-16.

Save the file as UTF-8 instead.

Answer (score 5):

You've found something called the [Byte Order Marker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) -- some Windows programs like to add these bytes (against the recommendations of the Unicode standard), to help them figure out how to parse these files again in the future.

I'd recommend using a different text editor than `notepad.exe`; `vim` or something similar ought to let you remove those bytes without too much hassle, and then they won't come back so long as you stick to the editors that don't insert garbage into your files.